# Nativescript - WebView / HtmlView + 3rd party javascript

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

We have found that the nativescript ui pie chart is not going to be sufficient for our needs. From what I can tell, we might be able to do one of two things to use a third part javascript solution:

- HtmlView
- WebView with the source being local files

I'm not sure about 2 things with either solution:

1. Can we load 3rd party and custom javascript
2. Do we have the ability to listen to and trigger custom events (basically passing data/events to and from the web/html view and the containing component)

Answering those 2 questions would be huge for us, and then any potential examples would also be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible you could include third party scripts in WebView. But you will have to use absolute paths in Android & need a little patch work on iOS as described [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/6377#issuecomment-433322681) Here is a [Playground Sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=2Jslpt&v=8) for including images in WebView, the approach will be similar for any third party libraries.

You may use [nativescript-webview-interface](https://github.com/shripalsoni04/nativescript-webview-interface) plugin if you want to communicate between your JavaScript inside WebView and NativeScript runtime.